# Laravel ajax 404 not found error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

am getting an ajax 404 error while using laravel 5.0 and ajax and I cannot figure out why.

**My routes**

```
Route::post('user/saved/ [
'as' => 'delete-topics',
'uses' => 'TopicController@deleteTopic',    
]);
```

**My form**

```
    <form action="{{action('TopicController@deleteTopic')}}" method="post" class="deleteform">
        <input type="hidden" name="topic_id" value="{{$topic->topic_id}}">

        <input type="submit" value="delete">
        </form>
```

**My ajax call**

```
  // process the form
 $('.deleteform').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);


  var formData = {
    topic_id    : $form.find('input[name=topic_id]').val()
};  


// process the form
$.ajax({
  type    : 'POST', 
  url     : 'saved',
  data    : formData, 
  dataType  : 'json', 
  encode    : true
})
```

**My Controller**

```
public function deleteTopic()
{

    $topic_id = Request::get('topic_id');

    if(Auth::check())
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $delete_topic = DB::table('topic_save')->where('user_id', $user_id)->where('topic_id', $topic_id)->delete();
    }


    $data['success']  =  true; 
    $data['message']  =  'success';
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I have tried changing the url in the ajax call to 'user/saved' to match the routes but am still getting the same 404 error

Thanks guys.

Comment: What's the URL of the page you're submitting the form on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the url to the action you have set for the form. That would be:

```
url = $form.attr('action');
$.ajax({
  type    : 'POST', 
  url     : url,
  data    : formData, 
  dataType: 'json', 
  encode  : true
})
```

Answer (score 4):

you can just remove action property from your Form, because you don't use form submit, then change ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type    : 'POST', 
  url     : "{{ route('delete-topics') }}",
  data    : formData, 
  dataType: 'json', 
  encode  : true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form action itself is incorrect:

```
<form action="{{action('TopicController@deleteTopic')}}" method="post" class="deleteform">
```

instead of this use:

```
action="route_path"
```